# TypeError: $items is undefined jquery on each

Tags: jquery, variables

I have this error : TypeError: $items is undefined

```
var $item = new Array();
var $items = $.each(response, function (i, item) {
    $item[i] = $($($.parseHTML(item)));
    $items.add($item[i]);
});
$grid.append($items);
```

I have bad declare a variable, can you help me?

Comment: add var $items = new Array(); before using it

Comment: `var $item = [],
    $items = [];

$items = $.each(response, function (i, item) {
    $item[i] = $($($.parseHTML(item)));
    $items.push($item[i]);
});
$grid.append($items);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `var $items = new Array();`  to declare $items as an empty array, before using it

```
var $item = [];
var $items = [];

$items = $.each(response, function (i, item) {
    $item[i] = $($($.parseHTML(item)));
    $items.push($item[i]);
});
$grid.append($items);
```

Comment: Better to use `[]` to declare empty array

Comment: TypeError: $items.add is not a function
 

$items.add($item[i]);

Comment: @Tushar: Thanks for improving my answer

Comment: yes. you can use "push" instead. I focussed on your error rather than code.

Comment: When i use "push" i have this "error TypeError: $items.addClass is not a function
$items.addClass(["

Comment: where are you using `addClass` function ?

Comment: does this code work? what is the use of $items = $.each or $($($.parseHTML(item)));

Comment: @NithishThomas : ya it works `$.each` is used for looping through the elements of an array(in this case `response` is an array). [REFERENCE](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and similarly for `$($($.parseHTML(item)))` [REFERENCE](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)

Comment: @SumitPandey sure it works but i think this is what the op is looking for https://jsfiddle.net/azvoyvdx/. No point in assigning $.each back to $.items. and we do not need to wrap $($.parseHTML(item)) again using $().