# TypeError: items.add is not a function inside each

Tags: jquery, function

I use jquery add() function.

```
$('body').on('click', '.loadmorebtn', function () {

    var $iaa = $('<div class="gallery-item item1">')
    var $bb = $('<div class="gallery-item item2">')
    var $cc = $iaa.add($bb); // Add OK
    console.log('itemee :', $cc); // return OK

    $.ajax({
        url: '/loadmore.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                var $item = [];
                var items = [];
                items = $.each(response, function (i, val) {
                    $item[i] = $($($.parseHTML(val)));
                    console.log('reponse:' + i, $item[i]);
                    // $(this).$($.add($item[i]));
                    items.add($item[i]); // Not ok
                    console.log('itemee >>>>> :', items);
                });
                $grid.append(items);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When I use it in each() :

> TypeError: items.add is not a function

I tried :

`items.($($.add($item[i]l)));`

`$(this).$($.add($item[i]));`

...

The function add () work on top, but not in ajax => success => each.

I think the call is not good with $ ($ ($

Comment: Use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add an item at the end of array. `items.push($item[i])` Already answered in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475171/typeerror-items-is-undefined-jquery-on-each) didn't you learned from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the top, you are calling add on the wrapped element set returned by jquery which succeeds because jquery library [defines](https://api.jquery.com/add/) that method.

But plain javascript array does not have that method. Perhaps you want to use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Alternatively you can create an empty wrapped element set and use jquery.add on that :

```
var items = $(null);
```

and later:

```
items = items.add($item[i]);
```